# Receive DJI Tello's video stream using Java

Tags: java, dji-sdk

I'm trying to write a java application for controlling the DJI Tello drone.

I'm already able to send simple commands to the drone by using *java.net.DatagramSocket* as client.
The Tello SDK says:
[image: imgur/screenshot]

It says I have to use *java.net.DatagramSocket* as the server to receive the video stream.
This is my try to receive the video stream:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;

public class TelloCamera extends Thread {
    private boolean isStreamOn;
    private DatagramSocket serverSocket;
    private byte[] receiveData = new byte[1470];

    public TelloCamera() {
        isStreamOn = true;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(11111);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        while (isStreamOn) {
            receiveData = new byte[1470];
            try {
                DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);

                String z = new String(receivePacket.getData());
                System.out.println(z);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            isStreamOn = false;
        }
        serverSocket.close();
    }

    public boolean isStreamOn() {
        return isStreamOn;
    }

    public void setStreamOn(boolean streamOn) {
        isStreamOn = streamOn;
    }
}
```

Main:

```
package tellotest;

public class maintellotest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TelloCommander tello = new TelloCommander();
        tello.sendCommand("command");
        tello.sendCommand("streamon");
        TelloCamera camera = new TelloCamera();
        camera.start();

    }
}
```

Does anybody know why I get no string printed to console?

Answer (score 0):

You have to send "streamon" command at 8889 port to Tello first and then listen at 11111 port. But in your code code, there is no code for sending the command. Try adding the code to send command first, send "command" then send "streamon" then listen on port 11111.

Comment: As you can see in the Main I am sending "command" and "streamon" via the TelloCommander object.

Comment: By the way, I am getting a string. Can you say what should I do with it. I want to convert it into a frame but IDK how?  Can anyone help me please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've also searched for a solution to this and came across a well implemented Tello java library, JTello @ https://github.com/xrv0/JTello.

In the library the author make use of JCodec (http://jcodec.org/) to decode the H.246 stream:

For example:

```
// byte[] message refers to the content of the datagram received from the drone over port 1111    
// Allocate output frame of max size
Picture out = Picture.create(1920, 1088, ColorSpace.YUV420);
Picture real = decoder.decodeFrame(ByteBuffer.wrap(message), out.getData());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an InetSocketAddress with IP "0.0.0.0" and port 11111 and then bind the socket to it. And also remove `isStreamOn = false` from the while loop.